# Python implementation to loop through entire text document

Tags: python, csv

I have lists within a list like this:

```
[['I','want','dog'],
['driving','a','car'],['S','O','S']
]
```

and a list like this `['yes','no',yes']`.

Now I want to do is import this data into a csv file like so:

```
yes, I want dog
no, driving a car
yes, S O S
```

can someone please help me out on this? It would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this with a simple list comprehension and `zip` -

```
x = [['I','want','dog'],
     ['driving','a','car'],
     ['S','O','S']]

y = ['yes','no','yes']

result = [[i,' '.join(j)] for i,j in zip(y, x)]
result
```

```
[['yes', 'I want dog'], 
 ['no', 'driving a car'], 
 ['yes', 'S O S']]
```

Then to ouptut to a csv you can use pandas -

```
import pandas as pd

pd.DataFrame(result).to_csv('output.csv')
```

[image]

Comment: Glad to help! Do mark the answer if it helped you and do upvote it if it’s well written to your liking. This encourages me to help solve your future questions :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to add the extra elements to each existing "row".

Then, use the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module to export that to a CSV file in the usual way.

Notice the use of [`iter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter) and [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) to insert the extra leading word into each "row", along with the use of [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) to combine the existing words in each "row" into a single column.

```
main = [
    ['I','want','dog'],
    ['driving','a','car'],
    ['S','O','S']
]

leading = iter(['yes','no','yes'])

joined = [[next(leading), ' '.join(m)] for m in main]

import csv

with open('output.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(joined)
```